# Using argparse with a specified acceptable option

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use argparse to accept required command line options.  I have defined a function like so

```
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Help Desk Calendar Tool')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', type=str, required=True, metavar='YYYY-MM-DD')
    parser.add_argument('-e','--end', type=str, required=True, metavar='YYYY-MM-DD')
    parser.add_argument('-m','--mode', type=str, required=True , metavar='add|del')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    start = args.start
    end = args.end
    mode = args.mode
    return start,end,mode
```

What I am trying to do is for the option --mode I would like it to ONLY accept an parameter of either add or del.  I could do this from an if statement but was wondering if argparse has a built in way of accomplishing this task.  I looked at nargs but wasn't too clear if that's the path I need to go down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking about `choices`:

```
parser.add_argument('-m','--mode', type=str, required=True, choices=['add', 'del'])
```

Demo:

```
$ python test.py -s 10 -e 20 -m invalid
usage: test.py [-h] -m {add,del}
test.py: error: argument -m/--mode: invalid choice: 'invalid' (choose from 'add', 'del')
```

Comment: I will look into that, the documentation was a little overwhelming for argparse.  Thank you

Comment: That was it!  Perfect.  Thanks